# Core Animation not working on Leopard, working on Snow Leopard

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nsimageview

I animate NSImageViews using its animator proxy.  While testing my application on Snow Leopard, everything works as expected.  However, on Leopard, none of the animations are functioning.  In addition, NSImageViews don't seem to take into effect the alphaValue I set on them, whether through the animator proxy or not.  The only way I can get them to disappear is by setting their image to nil.  What is weird is that this all works fine in Snow Leopard, but does not work on Leopard 10.5.8.  Any idea on why this may be occurring?

Answer (score 3):

This probably should have been in the AppKit release notes.  In 10.5, `-[NSView alphaValue]` only has any effect for layer backed views.  This limitation is lifted in 10.6.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to build against the 10.5 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It could just be a bug in Leopard that they fixed in Snow Leopard.